# SignalR transport falling back to longpolling in production

Tags: signalr

Just finished rewriting a chatsite with signalr in it.

Locally it works fine, after negotiating it uses server sent events all the time in firefox and chrome.

But:

If I test it on my server it always reverts to longpolling. My server isn't behind a proxy or firewall but server sent events shouldn't be affected by that anyway.

If I test it on my server locally (login via rdp and open a browser) it connects with server sent events again. So the setup is working, just something in the network that's causing the other transports to fail.

My question is: why would techniques like server sent events and foreverframe fail?

Comment: Is there any cross domain behavior occuring?  ForeverFrame and ServerSentEvents do not work cross domain.  You can follow the code execution path through to see if SignalR thinks the connection is cross domain

Comment: Thanks, but... what do you mean by 'follow the code execution path'?

Comment: Debug and step into the signalR source to see whats happening

Comment: Do you mean the client js code or the signalr server side code? The latter would be more difficult due to it being a server.

Comment: Just debugged the client js. The connection times out. After that it tries foreverframe, but there is an error in the code there because it checks if it supports SSE and if it does, it skips foreverframe. Still would like to know why there is a timeout though.

Comment: Turn logging on for the server and see if it detects any connections trying to connect with forever frame & server sent events.  So far from what your saying it seems like its not a SignalR issue but rather the server blocking in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the country the server is in (Thailand) has ISP's which almost all have some kind of proxy between the end user and the internet (one can only guess for what reason that is).

After trying from outside the country I got other transports and even got SSE via a local 3g mobile provider (yaay).